# How to build bloom filter with size that can not fit in RAM?

Tags: hadoop, data-structures, bigdata

Suppose we have to build a Bloom filter with 10^12 buckets on one machine with 32 GB RAM and a hard drive. Assume the keys are small and already on the hard drive. How could we build it in an efficient way?
My guess is to split Bloom filter into 4 parts (125GB / 4 fits into 32GB). Then pass through data 4 times each time hashing and updating corresponding slice in memory. Concatenate 4 slices back to get complete Bloom filter. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need so big filter ? Do you try to overestimate it in order to handle unbounded data as from a streaming source ? If yes, you can read about Stable Bloom filter and Scalable Bloom filter. Both are better adapted to such type of data than the classical Bloom filter.

To answer to your question, if you split your filter what you tell should work. But ensure that you deal with indexes correctly. If for instance the bit vector of 4 elements is splitted on 2 nodes, the first will be responsible for indexes (0, 1) and the second for (2, 3). You'll probably complicate it a little bit and store somewhere the mapping of what range is stored in what node and modify both reading and writing part accordingly.

You can also search for an example of implementation of so distributed Bloom filter. Maybe it'll give you another questioning points or, instead of developing your solution from scratch, you'll be able to test quickly how it behaves with your data pipeline.

In all cases, it would be great if you can give your short feedback here about how did you handled the problem and if you finally chosen another solution.